# boost::spirit. Parsing (name) (description) text to a map

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I currently working on parsing db schema in text file in the next format:

```
(table_name) (table_description)
```

The delimiter between elements are double return (`\n\n`)
I need to parse this to a map, using `boost::spirit` for parsing.

The problem is that the `table_description` can also contain double returns (`\n\n`).

The table_name has strict format, this is `*qi::char_("a-z0-9_")`.
The `table_description` can contain any chars, but always starts from upper-case later.

Any ideas how to create grammar for this parser?

Comment: "*The delimiter between elements are double return*" ... "*the `table_description` can also contain double returns*" Your format is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This closely resembles the article in Spirit docs: [Parsing a List of Key-Value Pairs Using Spirit.Qi](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/parsing-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-using-spirit-qi/) (Nov 15, 2009).

The most straightforward grammar I can think of for this, relies on the parentheses:

```
    start         = pair % "\n\n";
    parenthesized = '(' > *(char_ - ')') > ')';
    pair          = parenthesized >> "\n\n" >> parenthesized;
```

You could of course enhance it to require the exact syntax for table names and descriptions (starting with capital, e.g.) that you require, but the above is for illustration.

The only /nifty/ bits are:

- the use of `char_ - ')'` to _greedily match anything within parentheses (note this doesn't yet support nested sets of parentheses)
- the use of fusion adaptor for std::pair to parse into std::pair directly
- the use of `qi::blank` (not `qi::space`) skipper to avoid ignoring the newlines

Here is a full sample:

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> map_t;

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, map_t(), Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        // using phx::bind; using phx::ref; using phx::val;

        start         = pair % "\n\n";
        pair          = parenthesized >> "\n\n" >> parenthesized;
        parenthesized = '(' > *(char_ - ')') > ')';

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(parenthesized);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(pair);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(start);
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper > parenthesized;
    qi::rule<It, std::pair<std::string, std::string>(), Skipper> pair;
    qi::rule<It, std::map <std::string, std::string>(), Skipper> start;
};

template <typename C, typename Skipper>
    bool doParse(const C& input, const Skipper& skipper)
{
    auto f(std::begin(input)), l(std::end(input));

    parser<decltype(f), Skipper> p;
    map_t data;

    try
    {
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,skipper,data);
        if (ok)   
        {
            std::cout << "parse success\n";
            std::cout << "data: " << karma::format(
                 (karma::auto_ << ": \"" << karma::auto_ << "\"") % karma::eol, 
                 data) << "\n";
        }
        else      std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

        if (f!=l) std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
        return ok;
    } catch(const qi::expectation_failure<decltype(f)>& e)
    {
        std::string frag(e.first, e.last);
        std::cerr << e.what() << "'" << frag << "'\n";
    }

    return false;
}

template <typename C>
    bool doParse(const C& input)
{
    return doParse(input, qi::blank);
}

int main()
{
    const std::string input = "(table_name)\n\n(table_description)\n\n(other_table)\n\n(other\n\ndescription)";
    bool ok = doParse(input);

    return ok? 0 : 255;
}
```

Test output:

```
parse success
data: other_table: "other

description"
table_name: "table_description"
```